# Adding two rows of different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to add the values of a row in table2 (for example Id2=2) to a row from table1 (for example Id=1). There are a total of 100+ columns in the MySQL database

**table1**

```
+---+---+---+---+
|Id1| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | <- selected row
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| n | 0 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

**table2**

```
+---+---+---+---+
|Id2| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | <- selected row
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| n | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

**Result: table1**

```
+---+---+---+---+
|Id1| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | <- updated
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| n | 0 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Tried a bunch of stuff already but it didn't work. Thought I would need to look something like:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Id=1) = (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Id=1) +  (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE Id=2)
```

Hope you guys can help me out :).

Comment: do you mean 100 columns in a table? OMG databases are not spreadsheets.

Comment: @e4c5 it was actually an app I wrote in excell/vba, and now an online version. Seems that mysql is not a proper instrument, can you recommend something else? Redis?

Comment: Mysql is a proper 'instrument' it's just that how data is structured in RDBMS is very different from a spreadsheet. If you want to preserve the spreadsheet like nature you will need to use a nosql system.

Answer (score 0):

that syntax doesn't work. you need updated each column individually.
If you can manage to get a common key between 2 tables, you can follow below syntax.

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price+items.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

Further reference here.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: thanks unfortunately only the columns are equal for the two tables. Looks like I need to do 100+ queries, isn't?

Comment: if your id matching is always like 1 to 2. you can say id=id+1. then you can just write as  above query. If not, you have to select each destination column values and update source table.